# Why is the exterior algebra a bi-algebra (and even a Hopf algebra)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

According to the wikipedia, the exterior algebra of a $\Bbbk$-vector space $V$ is initial with respect to being unital and there existing a $\Bbbk$-linear map $j\colon V\to A$ such that $j(v)^2=0$ for all $v\in V$.

This is a reasonable algebra to consider if one is interested in measuring $k$-dimensional volumes, which are specified by $k$ linearly independent vectors, and which are degenerate if the vectors are not linearly independent (equivalently, for $char \Bbbk\neq 2$, measuring $k$-dimensional signed volumes). Then multiplication consists simply of throwing in extra vectors.

My question, inspired by the recent question on [the meaning of addition in the exterior algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50173/400), is about the meaning of co-multiplication. I happen to know virtually nothing about co-algebras outside of their formalism, so in part I am looking for answers that will help me build some intuition, geometric and otherwise, about what's happening.

1. What is a categorical argument that the exterior algebra satisfying the above universal property has co-multiplication (and is thus a bi-algbera)?
2. Is there a (heurisitc) geometric interpretation of the exterior algebra's co-multiplication similar to the $k$-dimensional volume tracking I sketched above?
3. (Bonus question): Is there any geometric significance to the anti-pode that makes the exterior (bi-)algebra into a Hopf algebra?

Comment: I cannot see what your second paragraph means, really...

Comment: Heuristically, I think of non-zero elements $v_1\wedge v_2\dots\wedge v_k$ of the exterior algebra as assigning to the (oriented) parallelepiped generated by $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ a $k$-dimensional signed volume of $1$. Multiplication then naturally takes us from assigning $k-$ and $l$-dimensional volumes to the parallelepipeds generated by $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_l)$ to assigning $k+l$-dimensional signed volumes by assigning $k+l$-dimensional volume $1$ to the parallelepipied generated by $(v_1,\dots,v_k,w_1,\dots,w_l)$, unless the parallelepiped generated is of dimension $<k+l$.

Comment: if that helps you, I guess it's all great! :) In any case, not all elements of the exterior algebra are of the form $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps it is first easier to understand why the *symmetric* algebra is a Hopf algebra. This is because $S(V)$ is nothing more than the ring of polynomial functions on $V^{\ast}$, and $V^{\ast}$ is naturally a [group scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_scheme) with vector addition as the group operation. Dualizing all of the maps you get from this group structure gives you precisely the Hopf algebra structure: you get the antipode from the inverse in $V^{\ast}$ and the comultiplication from the addition in $V^{\ast}$.

The exterior algebra is a sort of "twisted" symmetric algebra, so the same thing is true for it. One way to formalize this is that the exterior algebra is precisely the symmetric algebra, but where $V$ is regarded as an odd [supervector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space). This is because the [symmetric monoidal structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braided_monoidal_category#Symmetric_monoidal_categories) on supervector spaces is slightly different from what one might expect: it is given by $a \otimes b \mapsto (-1)^{|a| |b|} b \otimes a$. See, for example, [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/set-multiset-duality-and-supervector-spaces/).

I think there is a physical interpretation here, but I don't know how to be precise about it. The symmetric and exterior algebras are respectively the bosonic and fermionic [Fock spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space). The comultiplication ought to have a physical interpretation as "duplication of states," or something like that.

---

There is an idea you should understand if you haven't seen it before, and it is the notion of a [group object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object) in a category. If you write down what it means for an affine scheme $\text{Spec } R$ to be a group object in the category of affine schemes, then dualize all of the maps, you find that you have equipped $R$ with the structure of a Hopf algebra. A concise way to say this is that Hopf algebras are **cogroup objects** in a category of algebras, which just means that they are group objects in the opposite categories.

Answer (score 12):

Let $\Lambda V$ be the exterior algebra on $V$, and consider the tensor product algebra $\Lambda V\otimes\Lambda V$ in the sense of *graded* algebras, so that if $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are homogeneous elements in $\Lambda V$ we have $$a\otimes b\cdot c\otimes d=(-1)^{|b||c|}ac\otimes bd.$$ If $v\in V$, then you can chech that $(1\otimes v+v\otimes1)^2=0$. Therefore we have a map $$j:v\in V\mapsto v\otimes1+1\otimes v\in\Lambda V\otimes\Lambda V$$ such that $j(v)^2=0$ for all $v\in V$. As you observed, this $j$ then induces an algebra map $$\Delta:\Lambda V\to\Lambda V\otimes\Lambda V.$$ Using the universal property of $\Lambda V$ it is easy to show that this turns $\Lambda V$ into a Hopf algebra in the graded sense. For example, we need to show $\Delta$ is coassociative: but the maps $\Delta\otimes1_V\circ\Delta$ and $1_\V\otimes\Delta\circ\Delta$ are two algebra maps $\Lambda V\to\Lambda V\otimes\Lambda V\otimes\Lambda V$, so the universal property tells us that to check they coincide it is enough to show their restrictions to $V\subseteq\Lambda V$ coincide, and this can be done by computing explicitely.

It is important that the tensor product algebra $\Lambda V\otimes\Lambda V$ be taken in the *graded* sense here. In the ungraded sense, $\Lambda V$ is generally $not$ a Hopf algebra: for example, when $V$ is one dimensional, $\Lambda V\cong k[x]/(x^2)$ as an algebra and if the characteristic of the field $k$ is not two, this cannot be made into a Hopf algebra in any way.

Answer (score 2):

A hopf algebra structure on a space implies a hopf algebra structure on the dual space.The exterior algebra on a space has a natural a natural hopf algebra structure as was explained in the discussion via the initial object description.

There is a bonus symmetry in this situation. The two hopf algebra structures on the dual coincide.